# Django : Iterate over a query set without cache

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a dumb simple loop

```
for alias in models.Alias.objects.all() :
    alias.update_points()
```

but looking into the django QuerySet it seems to keep around a `_result_cache` of all the previous results. This is eating Gigs and Gigs of my machine and eventually everything blows up.

How can I throw away all the stuff that I won't ever care about?

Comment: try to rather do not use alias as a variable name - it's a keyword

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the queryset's [`iterator()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method to return the models in chunks, without populating the result cache:

```
for alias in models.Alias.objects.iterator() :
    alias.update_points()
```

Comment: Its still chewing through a ton of RAM when I use your call. :(

Comment: It is the fact that the mysql query is buffered that is causing all the ram trouble.

Comment: Have you tried setting the DEBUG to False? See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory This helped much more than using an iterator :)

Comment: If you are using Postgresql, upgrading to Django 1.11 and setting DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS to False will make this more RAM-efficient: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iterator

Answer (score 0):

You should consider saving your changes back to the database.

```
for alias in models.Alias.objects.all() :
    alias.update_points()
    alias.save()
```