# Django South migration leaks memory

Tags: django, memory-leaks, django-south

I am running Django 1.2.1 with South 0.7.2 and DEBUG = False.
Still a very simple data migration leaks memory:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
  for tr in orm.TestResult.objects.all():
    tr.software = tr.test_result.test_run.software
    tr.save()
```

The amount of TestResults is pretty big, but that should not be a real problem besides a long runtime. Unfortunately the process grows till my machine is out of memory.

Comment: I also tried to run `db.reset_queries()` after every loop iteration but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem to avoid the caching in the QuerySet:

```
for tr in orm.TestResult.objects.iterator() :
    tr.software = ...
```

It was already asked on SO here:

[Django : Iterate over a query set without cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443279/django-iterate-over-a-query-set-without-cache)

and the explanation in the Django docs:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better in your case to execute an sql upate query on all objects instead of updatnig records one by one. You can use [`execute`](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/databaseapi.html#db-execute) with an sql statement like this one (I don't know what database or data stucture you're using, so this is just an example):

```
UPDATE TestResult
   SET TestResult.software = TestRun.software
  FROM TestResult JOIN TestRun
       ON TestResult.test_run_id = TestRun.id
```